# Reading a CSV file in Flask and iterating through Jinga2

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I am trying to display data on my web app from a CSV file using Flask.  The below code reads my CSV file and assigns stocklist as the variable for my data. In the HTML code below it, using jinga logic, I iterate through stocklist however my CSV columns are returned as rows (see sample output and pic). How do I display the rows correctly?

**My python function:**

```
@app.route('/stocks')
def Stocks():
    filename = 'stock_scraper - dev.csv'
    data = pandas.read_csv(filename, header=0)
    stocklist = list(data.values.flatten())
    return render_template('stocks.html', stocklist=stocklist)
```

**My web app for iterating through stocklist:**

```
            <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>#</th>
                  <th>Ticker</th>
                  <th>Closing Price</th>
                  <th>Closing Date</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {% for eachstocks in stocklist%}
                <tr>
                  <td>{{ eachstocks }}</td>
                  <td>{{ eachstocks }}</td>
                  <td>{{ eachstocks }}</td>
                  <td>{{ eachstocks }}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

**Output:**
[image: table]

Answer (score 1):

Haks, i removed the nested loop and added the list position in each value to fix it. Works now.

```
          <tbody>
            {% for value in stocklist %}
                <tr>
                  <td>{{ value[0] }}</td>
                  <td>{{ value[1] }}</td>
                  <td>{{ value[2] }}</td>
                  <td>{{ value[3] }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
```

output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxi0f.png)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't flatten the list.

Try this:

```
@app.route('/stocks')
def Stocks():
    filename = 'stock_scraper - dev.csv'
    data = pandas.read_csv(filename, header=0)
    stocklist = list(data.values)
    return render_template('stocks.html', stocklist=stocklist)
```

Then for the Jinja template:

```
            <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>#</th>
                  <th>Ticker</th>
                  <th>Closing Price</th>
                  <th>Closing Date</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {% for value in stocklist%}
                <tr>
                  <td>{{ value[0] }}</td>
                  <td>{{ value[1] }}</td>
                  <td>{{ value[2] }}</td>
                  <td>{{ value[3] }}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: I get 16 columns with that.  see below. 

# Ticker Closing Price Closing Date
1 1 1 1 DODBX DODBX DODBX DODBX 100.69 100.69 100.69 100.69 02/22/19 02/22/19 02/22/19 02/22/19

Comment: Great to see you were able to fix it. I'll edit the solution now.