# Show csv content line by line by clicking button

Tags: javascript, html, flask, frontend

I'm new to frontend dev. I want to load a csv file's content and show one line's content at one time. Clicking a button will update the content to next line's. I also intend to have a form area to submit text to update some data during going over the file.
Is it possible to achieve this using Flask?

Comment: You will have more luck if you start working on the problem, and ask about specific issues.  As asked, the question lacks focus.

Comment: Yes, here is [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54854498/reading-a-csv-file-in-flask-and-iterating-through-jinga2/54854673) how it can be done